# regexp remove white space from string but not between ' or "

Tags: php, regex

How to remove all whitespaces from string but not between single or double qoutes?

for example, I have text:

```
$request = $requests[ $requestsCnt];
var_dump($request );
var_dump( getmypid());

$query = 'SELECT  FROM users';

$query2 = 'SELECT `*` FROM       
   `users`';

die;

$array = [ '    ' => 'bb']
```

I need to preserve whitespaces in `$query` and `$query2`
My regexp is `\s+(?![^'].*')`, but in doesn't work with:

```
$query2 = 'SELECT `*` FROM       
`users`';
```

and

```
$array = [ '    ' => 'bb']
```

Comment: you question does not seems clear enough

Comment: why? What i need to add?

Comment: do you want to remove breaklines?

Comment: No, I want to remove all white spaces, this string $array = [ '    ' => 'bb'] myst be $array=['    '=>'bb']

Comment: @Vladimir is [this](https://regex101.com/r/4BEhLo/1) what you need?

Comment: @Vladimir did your question get resolved?

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression will remove all *horizontal* whitespace (to preserve new lines) from a string (in this case, it seems to ve a PHP file):

```
\h+(?=([^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)

**Details**

\h                     # Any whitespace except new lines, one or more times
(?=                    # Positive lookahead
([^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$  # Match anything in between single quotes
)
```

**PHP example**

```
<pre>
<?php
$s = '
$request = $requests[ $requestsCnt];
var_dump($request );
var_dump( getmypid());

$query = \'SELECT  FROM users\';

$query2 = \'SELECT `*` FROM       
`users`\';

die;

$array = [ \'    \' => \'bb\']';
$s = preg_replace("/\h+(?=([^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)/i", "", $s);
echo nl2br($s); // <pre> and nl2br() to show formatted code
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/OdiAv)